# FileField not working with ArrayField in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, visual-studio, django-rest-framework

Using FileField inside ArrayField in Django For Multiple File Uploads but ArrayField is taking the files as string and not saving the files.

If the Above Cannot work is there any other working way in Django for Multiple File Upload.

I have tried some of the solutions available but none of those seemed/worked relevently for the case

Models.py

```py
class Questions(models.Model):

    def content_file_name(self, name):
        return 
    outside_asset = ArrayField(models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name, blank = True,default=False),default=[],blank=True)
    unquoted_shares = ArrayField(models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name, blank = True,default=False),default=[],blank=True)
    capital_gains = ArrayField(models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name, blank = True,default=False),default=[],blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Questionnarie'
        managed = True
```

views.py

```py
outside_asset_list = []
unquoted_shares_list = []
capital_gains_list = []

if form.is_valid():

    for x in request.FILES:
        val = x
        print('val :', val)
        files = request.FILES.getlist(val)
        print('files inside loop :', files)
        if val == 'outside_asset':
            for f in files:
                filename = f
                outside_asset_list.append(filename)
                print(outside_asset_list)
            print('files :', outside_asset_list)
        elif val == 'unquoted_shares':
            for f in files:
                filename = f
                unquoted_shares_list.append(filename)
            print('files :', unquoted_shares_list)
        elif val == 'capital_gains':
            for f in files:
                filename = f
                capital_gains_list.append(filename)
            print('files :', capital_gains_list)
    Questions.objects.create(user=user, year=year,
                             outside_asset=outside_asset_list,
                             unquoted_shares=[unquoted_shares_list],
                             capital_gains=[capital_gains_list])
    return Response....
```

All the files sent in request should be uploaded to a specific folder and their path should be saved as a list in the database in a single row

Comment: A `FileField` does not save the files. The `FileField` stores the files in the media directory, and keeps a reference of the filename. Furthermore, please do *not* use `default=[]`, but `default=list`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem FileField is not even storing the files in media directory.Further can you explain default=list. –

Comment: by using `default=[]`, you pass a reference to the same list, so if there are multiple `Questions` objects with the default, these will refer to the same list, and modifications to the first `Questions` object will have impact on the second (and vice versa). By using `list`, you pass a callable, and it will create a new list as default.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you share me some code for the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `ArrayField` does not support `FileField`s :(. [There's an open ticket on this issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25756), and there's even a "dirty" implementation of one in the thread - 4 years old already though.

What I usually do is have a separate model to hold the files, keeping a foreign key to the main model you have, something like this:

```
class Question(models.Model):

    <your_model_here>


class OutsideAsset(models.Model):

    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Question,
        related_name='outside_assets',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    file = models.FileField(...)
```

and you can repeat this for the other fields `unquoted_shares` and `capital_gains`.

Comment: Is there any other way for multiple file upload

Comment: There's a code excerpt on the ticket I linked: https://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/25756/multiple.py
However I'd advise you to only use it if you're able to understand everything that the code is doing - specially because I'm not even sure it's gonna be a plug and play kinda thing.